# Web design - zoom level changes website layout

Tags: html, css, mobile, web, zooming

What do I need to do, in terms of HTML/CSS, to design a webpage similar to [Project Tango](https://www.google.com/atap/projecttango/) and [Relevant Magazine](http://www.relevantmagazine.com/)

1. Whereby when I zoom in(through a desktop browser) to about 200%, the layout of the website changes and the whole navigation bar on top changes into that 3 parallel line thing.
2. The website content also automatically adjusts to not go beyond the
   horizontal view and hence, no need for horizontal scrolling.
3. This website layout adjusts automatically when I browse those pages via
   my Android browser.

How do I achieve this?

Sorry if something similar has been asked/posted up, but I honestly don't know how to describe it to be able to find it. Tried Googling with all possible terms I could think of(from zoom level to HTMLL5 & CSS3) to describe it but nothing came up.

Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing here is called [responsive design](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=responsive+design), where the layout of the page responds and adjusts to the size of the device/viewport it is being used on. The "three parallel line thing" is what's known as an ["off canvas menu"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=off+canvas+menu).

Answer (score 0):

It's not zoom level, it's device/viewport dimensions.

This is called a responsive layout.

You can do this using media queries. For example, this turns color red on screens larger than 600px:

```
@media (max-width: 599px) {
    body {
        color: black;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    body {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

What happens, when you zoom in, that even though the "physical" size of your window remains, the browser uses a smaller virtual screen to render to, then fits the rendered image to your real viewport sizes. You don't get blurry image, because they change rendering resolution cleverly, so they can re-size their output with minimal or in some cases zero quality loss. This is used by most industry-leading browsers today.

If you need to use zoom level, not media queries, then I'm afraid you are left with tricky options only. Each browser handles zooming differently. Some browsers only increase `font-size`, for example. Vast majority of browsers used this method a couple years ago. Today most browsers zoom the whole page. So the specifications may vary in different browsers and different versions as well. So you need to somehow emulate zooming, to achieve a consistent experience. Which does not seems to be a very good idea.

Comment: Just a quick note on browsers and pixel rendering it's best to start the new media query at a 1px difference - max-width 600px and min-width 600px are the same and would conflict/compete